# Create Compiled Function - Matrix Initialization

Tags: warning-messages, compile

I am attempting to compile the following function:

[image]

But I receive the following error messages:

[image]

How should I initialize the matrix Vw to enable the assignment to Vw[[1,1]]?

```
cKalmanIterateInit = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {cointwgts, _Real, 2}, {bb, _Real, 
2}, {bm, _Real, 2}, {cCovb, _Real, 2}} ,
Module[{b = bb, Covb = cCovb, X, Y, Yport, Yhat, k, n, i, a, G, 
w, Vw, e, Ve},
  {k, n} = Dimensions@data; Vw = Table[0., {k}, {k}];
   Y = data[[1]];
   Yport = cointwgts.data;
   X = data;
   X[[1, All]] = 1;
   Yhat = Total[b*X]; 
   a = IdentityMatrix[k];
  a[[1, 1]] = 
Max[-1.0, 
 Min[1.0, (b[[1, 
       2 ;; n]].b[[1, ;; (n - 1)]])/(b[[1, ;; (n - 
          1)]].b[[1, ;; (n - 1)]])]];
   G = b.\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*SuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(\[Transpose]\)]\)/n; Covb[[1]] = 
DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[(b - bm).Transpose[b - bm]/(n - 1)];
   w = b[[All, 2 ;; n]] - a.b[[All, ;; (n - 1)]];  
  Vw = DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[w.\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(\[Transpose]\)]\)]/(n - 1); 
   Vw[[1, 1]] = (1 - a[[1, 1]]^2)*G[[1, 1]];
   e = Y - Yhat;  (* measurment prediction error *)
   Ve = e.e/n;        (* measurement error variance  *)
  b[[All, 1]] = Join[{0}, -cointwgts[[2 ;; k]]]/cointwgts[[1]];
  {Y, X, a, b, bm, Ve, Vw, Covb}], {{Covb, _Real, 3}},
  Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

> Compile::cset: Variable Vw of type {_Real,2} encountered in assignment of type {_Real,0}.

Comment: One can initialize as `Vw = Table[0., {m}, {n}]` with suitable `m` and `n` and fill the matrix afterwards. Since I don't have your code in copyable code, I won't try.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to post the code but for some reason it kept messing up the formatting.

Comment: I posted the code. (a very laborious process!).  Anyway the suggested initialization of Vw didn't work in this case.

Comment: Try `Module[{..., Vw = {{0.}},...}...]`.

Comment: Hmmm. I see a major problem here: You're return value of your function is none of `Real`, `Integer`, `Complex`, `True|False` or a packed array of these data types, this `Compile` cannot be used. With _LibraryLink_, it is in principle possible to return several values of different types by one library function call (you have to supply the pointers to the fields for the return values as shared variable to the library function). But I doubt that this would execute significantly faster than directly in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Moreover, ``\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(\[Transpose]\)]\)`` and ``\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*SuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(\[Transpose]\)]\)`` are quite some abominations and the syntax highlighting tells me that they are not what you expect. Just use `Transpose[w]` and `Transpose[b]` in case of doubt.

Comment: One more thing: Please provide also some example data as input (or better: a way to generate random data as input). It is not easy to read off possible dimensions from just the code. Btw.: The line `Join[{0}, -cointwgts[[2 ;; k]]]` tells me that the rank specification of the second argument should be `{cointwgts, _Real, 1}`. Moreover, with `Join[{0}, -cointwgts[[2 ;; k]]]` you tell the function to join an integer vector with a real vector(?) That's not possible in compiled code. Use ``Join[{0.}, -cointwgts[[2 ;; k]]]`` instead (notice the decimal dot).

Comment: Huh. What is `Covb[[1]] = 
  DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[(b - bm).Transpose[b - bm]/(n - 1)];` supposed to do?You try to write a matrix into the first row of matrix `Covb`!

Comment: I suggest you give us the code you are using that works **before** attempting to `Compile[]` it. Having working code makes things a lot easier to understand.